# How can I extract a still image with subtitles from a movie?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to obtain a still image with subtitles from movie data.
But I do not know how to do it.
I know the method without subtitles.

```
ffmpeg -ss 1001 -i input.mkv -vframes 1 1001.jpg
```

Also, subtitle data is included in movie data

```
Stream # 0: 4 (jpn): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (default)
```

It is contained as shown.
It can also export as sup.

What kind of command can we do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 1001 -copyts -i input.mkv -filter_complex [0:v][0:4]overlay -vframes 1 1001.jpg
```

Comment: thank you Gyan.I resolved 'ffmpeg -ss 1001 -copyts -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v][0:4]overlay" -vframes 1 1001.jpg'